# How To Programatically 'Gift This App' To Another AppleID Account Holder?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, itunes-store

It is possible to 'Gift This App' to another AppleID account holder - i.e. another person.

Is there any way of wiring up a button within my app to allow the user to gift the app to another? Similar to the standard 'Rate Me' function, but to direct the user directly to the 'Gift This App' option.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: check: http://www.imore.com/how-gift-app-store-apps-straight-your-iphone-and-ipad

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I know how to do it on a handset. I just want to know if there is a way of programatically sending the user directly to the gift option at the store for a specific product ID.